# jQuery | Cannot get href of the active tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I am trying to get the href of the current active tab using jQuery but It doesn't seem to work.

here is my html

```
        <div class="profile">
        <div  class="tabbable-line tabbable-full-width">
            <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#tab_1_1" data-toggle="tab"> Overview </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#tab_1_2" data-toggle="tab"> Loan Details </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#tab_1_3" data-toggle="tab"> Edit Details </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#tab_1_6" data-toggle="tab"> Delete Account </a>
                </li>
```

after searching on this site for some time

I tried doing :

```
var data = $("#tabs li.active").prop("href");
alert(data);
```

also :

```
var data = $(".profile li.active").prop("href");
alert(data);
```

but both of them give me output as `undefined`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not targeting the `<a>` element in your selector.

Try

```
var data = $(".profile li.active a").prop("href");
alert(data);
```

or

```
var data = $("#tabs li.active a").prop("href");
alert(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

**href** is not the property of **li** element, so you will be getting **udefined** in your data variable. You should point to  tag in your selector as shown below :

```
var data = $("#tabs li.active a").prop("href");
alert(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think use attr() is better,Bind with a event is better.

```
var data = $(".profile li.active a").attr("href");
alert(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with `attr()` rather than `prop()`.

```
var href= $($('ul#tabs>li.active').find('a')[0]).attr("href");
alert(href);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are not locating to the anchor tag try this.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.active').click(function(){
        var href = $('a').attr('href');
        alert(href);
    });
});
```